# Gradle Download repo1.maven.org stuck

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, gwt, vmware

Im running a OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 VM (VMware) on my windows PC. So far everything has worked great, however now that I try to sync my project it keeps getting stuck at `Gradle: Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.1/gwt-user-2.6.1.jar`.

It downloads some other Gradle dependencies before this very quickly, so not sure what the issue here is. My Gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.12.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "SpaceFriends"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        gdxPayVersion = '0.10.3'
        gdxFacebookVersion = '1.2.2'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-desktop:$gdxFacebookVersion"
    }
}
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    }

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile fileTree(dir: '../core/libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
            force = true
        }
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:$gdxFacebookVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android:$gdxPayVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-googleplay:${gdxPayVersion}@aar"
    }
}
project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-ios:$gdxFacebookVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-iosrobovm-apple:$gdxPayVersion"
    }
}
project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-html:$gdxFacebookVersion"
    }
}
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-core:$gdxFacebookVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:$gdxPayVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar")
    }
}
tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

I downloaded the file and could link to it locally, but not sure how, i.e I am not sure what in my gradle prompts this download (?)

Edit: Running `/gradlew clean` also starts the download from `services.gradle.org`, but never finishes.

Edit2: Worth mentioning that my Gradle.build works just fine on my PC running the same project.

Comment: That jar file is 29MB large. The other jar files were probably much smaller, and thus much faster to download.

Comment: @JBNizet 29mb should take about 5 seconds though on my internet. Ill let it run overnight and see what happens.

Comment: I gave it about 30 minutes before I figured something must be wrong,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is specific to an OS running on VMware.

Anyone running into this issue, or just a general issue of not being able to connect and download things from terminal, change your network adapter from NAT to bridged.